# copy style and data in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I would like to copy all the data and the style of a certain range to other cells. for example I want to copy from A4: I15 and then paste exactly want I copied the contents and styles from A16. How can I do it?. this is what I want to copy:

[image]

I know only copy the data but not the style and do it with this code:

```
$cellValues = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A4:I15');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($cellValues, null, 'A16');
```

I need copy the styes.. and the data

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258318/workaround-for-copying-style-with-phpexcel/18262601#18262601) answer your question at all?

Answer (score 9):

```php
function copyRows(PHPExcel_Worksheet $sheet,$srcRow,$dstRow,$height,$width) {
    for ($row = 0; $row < $height; $row++) {
        for ($col = 0; $col < $width; $col++) {
            $cell = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $srcRow + $row);
            $style = $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($col, $srcRow + $row);
            $dstCell = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($col) . (string)($dstRow + $row);
            $sheet->setCellValue($dstCell, $cell->getValue());
            $sheet->duplicateStyle($style, $dstCell);
        }

        $h = $sheet->getRowDimension($srcRow + $row)->getRowHeight();
        $sheet->getRowDimension($dstRow + $row)->setRowHeight($h);
    }

    foreach ($sheet->getMergeCells() as $mergeCell) {
        $mc = explode(":", $mergeCell);
        $col_s = preg_replace("/[0-9]*/", "", $mc[0]);
        $col_e = preg_replace("/[0-9]*/", "", $mc[1]);
        $row_s = ((int)preg_replace("/[A-Z]*/", "", $mc[0])) - $srcRow;
        $row_e = ((int)preg_replace("/[A-Z]*/", "", $mc[1])) - $srcRow;

        if (0 <= $row_s && $row_s < $height) {
            $merge = $col_s . (string)($dstRow + $row_s) . ":" . $col_e . (string)($dstRow + $row_e);
            $sheet->mergeCells($merge);
        } 
    }
}
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("x.xlsx");
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
copyRows($sheet, 1, 50, 48, 11);
copyRows($sheet, 2, 7 + 5, 5, 5);
copyRows($sheet, 2, 7 + 10, 5, 5);
copyRows($sheet, 2, 7 + 15, 5, 5);
```

Comment: I was looking for that, Thx for sharing it :)

Comment: Upvoted, because it works, However, it does not copy formula across to the new row dynamically

Answer (score 9):

Update: [@pavelDD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9593787/paveldd) pointed out that since version 1.x.x some of the imports has been renamed. Instead of accepting his edits to the original code I will share new version. Besides the renaming I've also fixed the annoying index bug and added a helper that copies styles from the original sheet. Unfortunately I'm too lazy to convert it from a class to a simple function like I did last time. But based on the previous version you should be able to do that by yourself if needed.

```
<?php
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate;

class Utils {
    public static function copyRows( Worksheet $sheet, $srcRange, $dstCell, Worksheet $destSheet = null) {

        if( !isset($destSheet)) {
            $destSheet = $sheet;
        }

        if( !preg_match('/^([A-Z]+)(\d+):([A-Z]+)(\d+)$/', $srcRange, $srcRangeMatch) ) {
            // Invalid src range
            return;
        }

        if( !preg_match('/^([A-Z]+)(\d+)$/', $dstCell, $destCellMatch) ) {
            // Invalid dest cell
            return;
        }

        $srcColumnStart = $srcRangeMatch[1];
        $srcRowStart = $srcRangeMatch[2];
        $srcColumnEnd = $srcRangeMatch[3];
        $srcRowEnd = $srcRangeMatch[4];

        $destColumnStart = $destCellMatch[1];
        $destRowStart = $destCellMatch[2];

        $srcColumnStart = Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($srcColumnStart);
        $srcColumnEnd = Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($srcColumnEnd);
        $destColumnStart = Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($destColumnStart);

        $rowCount = 0;
        for ($row = $srcRowStart; $row <= $srcRowEnd; $row++) {
            $colCount = 0;
            for ($col = $srcColumnStart; $col <= $srcColumnEnd; $col++) {
                $cell = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $style = $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
                $dstCell = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($destColumnStart + $colCount) . (string)($destRowStart + $rowCount);
                $destSheet->setCellValue($dstCell, $cell->getValue());
                $destSheet->duplicateStyle($style, $dstCell);

                // Set width of column, but only once per column
                if ($rowCount === 0) {
                    $w = $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($col)->getWidth();
                    $destSheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn ($destColumnStart + $colCount)->setAutoSize(false);
                    $destSheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn ($destColumnStart + $colCount)->setWidth($w);
                }

                $colCount++;
            }

            $h = $sheet->getRowDimension($row)->getRowHeight();
            $destSheet->getRowDimension($destRowStart + $rowCount)->setRowHeight($h);

            $rowCount++;
        }

        foreach ($sheet->getMergeCells() as $mergeCell) {
            $mc = explode(":", $mergeCell);
            $mergeColSrcStart = Coordinate::columnIndexFromString(preg_replace("/[0-9]*/", "", $mc[0]));
            $mergeColSrcEnd = Coordinate::columnIndexFromString(preg_replace("/[0-9]*/", "", $mc[1]));
            $mergeRowSrcStart = ((int)preg_replace("/[A-Z]*/", "", $mc[0]));
            $mergeRowSrcEnd = ((int)preg_replace("/[A-Z]*/", "", $mc[1]));

            $relativeColStart = $mergeColSrcStart - $srcColumnStart;
            $relativeColEnd = $mergeColSrcEnd - $srcColumnStart;
            $relativeRowStart = $mergeRowSrcStart - $srcRowStart;
            $relativeRowEnd = $mergeRowSrcEnd - $srcRowStart;

            if (0 <= $mergeRowSrcStart && $mergeRowSrcStart >= $srcRowStart && $mergeRowSrcEnd <= $srcRowEnd) {
                $targetColStart = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($destColumnStart + $relativeColStart);
                $targetColEnd = Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($destColumnStart + $relativeColEnd);
                $targetRowStart = $destRowStart + $relativeRowStart;
                $targetRowEnd = $destRowStart + $relativeRowEnd;

                $merge = (string)$targetColStart . (string)($targetRowStart) . ":" . (string)$targetColEnd . (string)($targetRowEnd);
                //Merge target cells
                $destSheet->mergeCells($merge);
            }
        }
    }

    public static function copyStyleXFCollection(Spreadsheet $sourceSheet, Spreadsheet $destSheet) {
        $collection = $sourceSheet->getCellXfCollection();

        foreach ($collection as $key => $item) {
            $destSheet->addCellXf($item);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I've taken Prashant's answer and extended it for easier use and added some additional functionality. It was a great source to begin with. But it was missing some key features for me:
Taking a range (e.g. A10:B15) instead of just indexes
Taking a destination cell rather then just a row.
Setting width of the destination columns

*Please note that I'm using PHPSpreadsheet, the successor of PHPExcel.
If you are using the older version just need to update the path for the Cell class.*

```
<?php
/** 
 * Copy range in PHPSpreadsheet/PHPExcel including styles
 **/

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Worksheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Cell;


function copyRange( Worksheet $sheet, $srcRange, $dstCell) {
    // Validate source range. Examples: A2:A3, A2:AB2, A27:B100
    if( !preg_match('/^([A-Z]+)(\d+):([A-Z]+)(\d+)$/', $srcRange, $srcRangeMatch) ) {
        // Wrong source range
        return;
    }
    // Validate destination cell. Examples: A2, AB3, A27
    if( !preg_match('/^([A-Z]+)(\d+)$/', $dstCell, $destCellMatch) ) {
        // Wrong destination cell
        return;
    }

    $srcColumnStart = $srcRangeMatch[1];
    $srcRowStart = $srcRangeMatch[2];
    $srcColumnEnd = $srcRangeMatch[3];
    $srcRowEnd = $srcRangeMatch[4];

    $destColumnStart = $destCellMatch[1];
    $destRowStart = $destCellMatch[2];

    // For looping purposes we need to convert the indexes instead
    // Note: We need to subtract 1 since column are 0-based and not 1-based like this method acts.

    $srcColumnStart = Cell::columnIndexFromString($srcColumnStart) - 1;
    $srcColumnEnd = Cell::columnIndexFromString($srcColumnEnd) - 1;
    $destColumnStart = Cell::columnIndexFromString($destColumnStart) - 1;

    $rowCount = 0;
    for ($row = $srcRowStart; $row <= $srcRowEnd; $row++) {
        $colCount = 0;
        for ($col = $srcColumnStart; $col <= $srcColumnEnd; $col++) {
            $cell = $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $style = $sheet->getStyleByColumnAndRow($col, $row);
            $dstCell = Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($destColumnStart + $colCount) . (string)($destRowStart + $rowCount);
            $sheet->setCellValue($dstCell, $cell->getValue());
            $sheet->duplicateStyle($style, $dstCell);

            // Set width of column, but only once per row
            if ($rowCount === 0) {
                $w = $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($col)->getWidth();
                $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn ($destColumnStart + $colCount)->setAutoSize(false);
                $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn ($destColumnStart + $colCount)->setWidth($w);
            }

            $colCount++;
        }

        $h = $sheet->getRowDimension($row)->getRowHeight();
        $sheet->getRowDimension($destRowStart + $rowCount)->setRowHeight($h);

        $rowCount++;
    }

    foreach ($sheet->getMergeCells() as $mergeCell) {
        $mc = explode(":", $mergeCell);
        $mergeColSrcStart = Cell::columnIndexFromString(preg_replace("/[0-9]*/", "", $mc[0])) - 1;
        $mergeColSrcEnd = Cell::columnIndexFromString(preg_replace("/[0-9]*/", "", $mc[1])) - 1;
        $mergeRowSrcStart = ((int)preg_replace("/[A-Z]*/", "", $mc[0]));
        $mergeRowSrcEnd = ((int)preg_replace("/[A-Z]*/", "", $mc[1]));

        $relativeColStart = $mergeColSrcStart - $srcColumnStart;
        $relativeColEnd = $mergeColSrcEnd - $srcColumnStart;
        $relativeRowStart = $mergeRowSrcStart - $srcRowStart;
        $relativeRowEnd = $mergeRowSrcEnd - $srcRowStart;

        if (0 <= $mergeRowSrcStart && $mergeRowSrcStart >= $srcRowStart && $mergeRowSrcEnd <= $srcRowEnd) {
            $targetColStart = Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($destColumnStart + $relativeColStart);
            $targetColEnd = Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($destColumnStart + $relativeColEnd);
            $targetRowStart = $destRowStart + $relativeRowStart;
            $targetRowEnd = $destRowStart + $relativeRowEnd;

            $merge = (string)$targetColStart . (string)($targetRowStart) . ":" . (string)$targetColEnd . (string)($targetRowEnd);
            //Merge target cells
            $sheet->mergeCells($merge);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Example usage:

```
copyRange($sheet, 'A4:B8', 'E1');
copyRange($sheet, 'A4:B8', 'A10');
copyRange($sheet, 'A4:B8', 'C17');
```

Note: I haven't tried it with a single cell. But in theory it should work with A1:A1

Please let me if I have made any mistake, or feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: Great work both of you! To make it work with ranges, though I had to remove all `- 1`, otherwise it would shift the destination range of one cell forward. For example: passing `copyRange($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet(), "A1:K48", "L1");` would start the content in `M1` instead of `L1` (as i would have expected)!

Comment: Thanks for the update @LukeSavefrogs! If I'm not mistaken I had to add the -1 due to a bug in PHPSpreadsheet. The documentation said one thing but the code did another. Maybe it's fixed now? You can feel free to update my answer with your changes if you have the possibility. And some kind of update statement on the top of the post

Comment: Can the `class` version be removed? As far as i can tell they are the same thing and the second (function) is just a refactor of the first...

Comment: The class version is the newer version of the code, where the index thing should be fixed. So if that's the one you use I'm not sure why you had that issue. I haven't used it myself since I wrote it 5 years ago so I guess thing might have changed. Maybe you know better then me which version is the best to keep. But the current function-version is not correct since the imports are wrong and it also has the index-bug that I've fixed in the class-version.

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution without additional code:

```
<?php

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\BaseReader;

/** @var BaseReader $reader */
$reader = IOFactory::createReaderForFile('old_file.xlsx');
$reader->setReadDataOnly(false);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load('old_file.xlsx');

$worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

/** Iterate needed cells in $worksheet and change their values **/

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('new_file.xlsx');
```

The important part is to set option **$reader->setReadDataOnly(false)** (which is set by default) because if option is set to true then only data without styles are read.